# Get values in complex numbers problem

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a problem, and I have advanced but I do not know how to get to the solution, which is $-2$

It says:

> If $3i + 5i^2 = a + bi$, so $a + b$ = ?

I need the value of $a + b$ given the data

I got here:

[Image of my resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIWDF.jpg)

In case you can not see it, my development was in:

$16 = (a + b)(a - b)$

Comment: Hint:

$3i+5i^2=3i+5(\sqrt{-1})^2=-5+3i$, which is in the form $a+bi$, where $a=-5$ and $b=3$.

Comment: $i^2 = -1$ So $3i + 5i^2 = 3i - 5 = -5 + 3i$.  So $a= -5$ and $b =3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Thus $i^2 = -1$. That means:

$$3i + 5i^2 = 3i + 5(-1) = 3i - 5 = -5 + 3i$$

So $a = -5$ and $b = 3$, and $-5 + 3 = -2$.

Comment: Thanks andrew !!